# Wordpress PHP - categories

Tags: php, wordpress

I think my previous question was over complicated and, to be honest, was confusing me, nevermind the people trying to answer.

I currently have to pages, both with one category of posts assigned to them, however both post pages are using the same content.php and content-single.php, but i was both pages to use different iterations of these pages for cosmetic reasons.

As an example, visit http://dev.n8geeks.com/blog/ and click on the first blog post. It displays a thumbnail, which is cool and is what i want. However, now on the "videos" page as seen here; http://dev.n8geeks.com/videos/ (once there, click on the post) it also shows the thumbnail box (but no thumbnails will be attached on this posts page category).

This is why i need to user different iterations of content.php and content-single.php, but i simply don't know how. It would also be great if the "videos" page had the same formatting as the "blog" page, but again, i don't know how to achieve this.

The code i'm using for the current "videos" page is as below.

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<div id="content">
<div id="main">

<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<?php the_content(); ?>
<?php endwhile; else: endif; ?>

<?php query_posts('category_name='.get_the_title().'&post_status=publish,future');?>
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<h1 class="entry-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
<?php the_title();  ?></a></h1>
<p><?php the_content(); ?>
<?php endwhile; else: endif; ?>

</div>
</div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Thanks in advance, i really appreciate any help like you wouldn't believe - it's 4:33am and i'm going insane trying to find a fix for this.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Still extremely confusing, haha, but from the sounds of it you want different templates to show up based on which category the post is in when you're viewing a single post?

If so, you could try setting this as you single.php:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

    <?php
        if ( have_posts() ) { the_post(); rewind_posts(); }
        if ( in_category(1) || in_category(2) ) {
            include(TEMPLATEPATH . '/single-cat1-2.php');
        }
        else {
            include(TEMPLATEPATH . '/single-default.php');
        }
    ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

(from http://wordpress.org/support/topic/alternate-single-post-template-for-specific-categories)

And create the files 'single-cat1-2.php' and 'single-default.php', just add to the if statement checking to see if the post is in a certain category (or categories) and load the correct template.  You can use ID, name, and their slug as selectors for the `in_category` function as well, [read more here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/in_category).

EDIT:
Kay, well you do need to learn plugin programming to really do this.  I've begun a quick plugin for you to help you out. It works, just isn't perfect.  You could definitely use a different system, like tying the categories in the category menu, but I didn't feel like playing with the Settings API for that page.

So make a new directory in your plugins directory, call it `PostCatTheme`, make a new file in there called `index.php` and put this in it:

```
<?php
/*
 * Plugin Name: Post Category Templates
 */
//Replace __FILE__ with whatever the real path is because of symbolic link

/**
 * Allows declarations of which categories a single-post template is assigned to
 */
class WordpressPostCatTheme
{
    private $pluginDir, $templates;

    function __construct ()
    {
        $this->pluginDir = dirname(__FILE__);

        add_action("init", array($this, "load"));
        add_filter('single_template', array($this, 'get_post_template'));
    }

    public function WPCT_deactivate ()
    {
        delete_option("PostCatTheme_templates");
    }

    public function load ()
    {
        register_deactivation_hook( __FILE__, array(&$this, 'WPCT_deactivate') );

        $this->templates = get_option("PostCatTheme_templates");
        if ($this->templates === FALSE)
        {
            $this->templates = $this->get_post_templates();
            update_option("PostCatTheme_templates", $this->templates);
        }
    }

    //  This function scans the template files of the active theme, 
    //  and returns an array of [category] => {file}.php]
    public function get_post_templates()
    {
        $themes = get_themes();
        $theme = get_current_theme();
        $templates = $themes[$theme]['Template Files'];
        $post_templates = array();

        $base = array(trailingslashit(get_template_directory()), trailingslashit(get_stylesheet_directory()));

        foreach ((array)$templates as $template)
        {
            $template = WP_CONTENT_DIR . str_replace(WP_CONTENT_DIR, '', $template); 
            $basename = str_replace($base, '', $template);

            // don't allow template files in subdirectories
            if (false !== strpos($basename, '/'))
                continue;

            $template_data = implode('', file( $template ));

            $categories = '';
            if (preg_match( '|Categories (.*)$|mi', $template_data, $categories))
                $categories = _cleanup_header_comment($categories[1]);

            //The categories are split by a | (pipe), if there aren't any pipes, assume it's just
            //one category, otherwise split at the pipe
            if (empty($categories))
                continue;

            if (strpos($categories, "|") === FALSE)
                $categories = array($categories);
            else
                $categories = explode("|", $categories);

            foreach ($categories as $category)
            {
                if (!empty($category))
                {
                    if (isset($post_templates[$category]))
                        throw new Exception("Error, category assigned to more than one template");

                    if(basename($template) != basename(__FILE__))
                        $post_templates[trim($category)] = $basename;
                }
            }
        }
        //file_put_contents($this->pluginDir . "/log", json_encode($post_templates));
        return $post_templates;
    }


    //  Filter the single template value, and replace it with
    //  the template chosen by the user, if they chose one.
    function get_post_template($template)
    {
        global $post;

        $cats = wp_get_post_categories($post->ID);

        //Go through each category, until one hits
        foreach ($cats as $c)
        {
            $templateP = $this->templates[$c];

            if(!empty($templateP) && file_exists(TEMPLATEPATH . "/{$templateP}"))
            { 
                $template = TEMPLATEPATH . "/{$templateP}";
                break;
            }
        }
        return $template;
    }
}

if (!isset($PostCatThemePlugin))
    $PostCatThemePlugin = new WordpressPostCatTheme;
?>
```

After that, in your custom single.php template, add the code `Categories: 1|2` in the header section (where `Template Name` is).  Whenever you change or add these, make sure to deactivate and reactivate the plugin, to refresh the cache that this information is stored in.

To get the ID of a category, edit a category and in the URL, the number after tag_ID= is the category's ID.

Hope that helps some,
Max

Comment: Hey Mazz, yeah, very confusing indeed! So basically i want different versions of content.php and content-single.php to show depending on  the category. Does the code above work for that? Thanks LOT for your time.

Comment: Yup, this should do that then :3, feel free to ask if you would like help implementing it.

Comment: I tried this and it didn't seem to work, argh. Is there any way i can contact you to resolve this? I'd be prepared to pay for a fix.

Comment: See the edited post, that plugin does it.  Feel free to work edit/modify whatever with it.  Hope that gives you a good start down the amazing path of Wordpress plugin development!